# Facebook /{user-id}/feed filters

Tags: facebook-graph-api, filter

Based on Facebook documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed
the **filter modifier** should retrieve only posts that match a particular stream filter.

So trying on the Graph API Explorer the following query: 

**me/feed?filter=app_2305272732** 
should only get me photo posts and not all posts like I'm getting back.

Has anyone any better luck with stream filters? Is this a facebook bug?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this a Facebook Bug and as of today it is not fixed. Below is the link to this bug, you can subscribe it to track its status.  [Bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/416005341940559)